# How to replace or add string using regex in vscode?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I want to add `.ts` in every file using find and replace in vscode.

for example, `import some from 'module'` to `import some from 'module.ts'`.

What the correct regex and the replacement todo that? I try this regex but i'm not sure how to do the replace...
`import(?:["'\s]*([\w*{}\n\r\t, ]+))from\s*?(["'\s].*([@\w/_-]+)(["'\s].*))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Find Regex:

```
import(?:["'\s]*([\w*{}\n\r\t, ]+)\s)from\s*?["'](\w.*)["'\s].*
```

Replace Regex:

```
import $1 from '$2.ts'
```

Comment: Good! and how to do that with `./`?  `import some from './module'`?

Comment: $2 is `(\w.*)` group, is which equals `module`, add to that group your `./` and it will work